# unable to run batch from asp.net on the server

Tags: asp.net, batch-file, process

I am trying to run batch file from asp.net. It is working correctly on my local machine. but when i deploy webapplication and batch file on the server, I am getting error something like "Access denied". 
When I change ApplicationPool identity to localsystem i am not getting any error but batch file didn't trigger. I have tried giving username and password for the process object in asp.net but without luck.

```
string path = @"C:\Users\mrahm13\AppData\test.bat";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You need to grant the AppPool permission to access that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out. I should disable impersonation in web.config besides giving permissions to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (not tested with ASP.NET):
Let your process be cmd.exe, and pass

```
/c C:\Users\mrahm13\AppData\test.bat
```

as arguments.